# how to merge rows from dataframes contained in lists in r

Tags: r, list, dataframe

i have 3 lists of dataframes , list x, y and z in this way

```
x
[1]
ID   1h   2h  3h
1    3     5  6
2    1     8  2
3    7     3  9
[2]
ID   1h   2h  3h
1    9     0  0
2    0     3  1
3    2     4  7
[3]
ID   1h   2h  3h
1    3     1  0
2    5     5  0
3    7     0  0
```

```
y
[1]
ID   1h   2h  3h
1    7     3  0
2    1     8  2
3    7     3  9
[2]
ID   1h   2h  3h
1    8     0  1
2    9     5  3
3    2     4  7
[3]
ID   1h   2h  3h
1    0     2  9
2    0     5  9
3    3     5  4
```

```
z
[1]
ID   1h   2h  3h
1    8     7  5
2    4     0  3
3    0     0  0
[2]
ID   1h   2h  3h
1    4     5  9
2    0     9  5
3    3     7  9
[3]
ID   1h   2h  3h
1    8     0  4
2    7     4  2
3    1     4  9
```

i want the result to take the ID of the first dataframe of x and merge it with the first ID of the first y dataframe and the first ID of the first z dataframe to look like this, **and and do this  for all the dataframes in the lists**:

```
ID1 [1]
      x     y  z
1h    3     7  8
2h    5     3  7
3h    6     0  5
```

to clarify more , here is an example with the 2nd ID of the 3rd dataframe of each list

```
ID2 [3]
      x     y  z
1h    5     0  7
2h    5     5  4
3h    0     9  2
```

and finally also export them in csv files with names containing the ID number (1,2 or 3) and which item of the list ([1],[2] or [3])
thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution. I used lists to reach what you want:

```
library(reshape2)
#Data
L1 <- list(structure(list(ID = 1:3, `1h` = c(3L, 1L, 7L), `2h` = c(5L, 
8L, 3L), `3h` = c(6L, 2L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(ID = 1:3, `1h` = c(9L, 0L, 2L), `2h` = c(0L, 
3L, 4L), `3h` = c(0L, 1L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(ID = 1:3, `1h` = c(3L, 5L, 7L), `2h` = c(1L, 
5L, 0L), `3h` = c(0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)))
L2 <- list(structure(list(ID = 1:3, `1h` = c(7L, 1L, 7L), `2h` = c(3L, 
8L, 3L), `3h` = c(0L, 2L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(ID = 1:3, `1h` = c(8L, 9L, 2L), `2h` = c(0L, 
5L, 4L), `3h` = c(1L, 3L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(ID = 1:3, `1h` = c(0L, 0L, 3L), `2h` = c(2L, 
5L, 5L), `3h` = c(9L, 9L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)))
L3 <- list(structure(list(ID = 1:3, `1h` = c(7L, 1L, 7L), `2h` = c(3L, 
8L, 3L), `3h` = c(0L, 2L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(ID = 1:3, `1h` = c(8L, 9L, 2L), `2h` = c(0L, 
5L, 4L), `3h` = c(1L, 3L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(ID = 1:3, `1h` = c(0L, 0L, 3L), `2h` = c(2L, 
5L, 5L), `3h` = c(9L, 9L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)))

#Format function
formatf <- function(x)
{
  y <- reshape2::melt(x,id.vars = 'ID')
  return(y)
}
#Apply
M1 <- lapply(L1,formatf)
M2 <- lapply(L2,formatf)
M3 <- lapply(L3,formatf)
#Merge function
fmerge <- function(a,b,c)
{
  d1 <- merge(a,b,by=c('ID','variable'))
  d2 <- merge(d1,c,by=c('ID','variable'))
  return(d2)
}
#Apply
LL=mapply(fmerge,M1,M2,M3,SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
#Format to export
names(LL)<-paste0('Group',1:length(LL))
#Bind all
DF <- do.call(rbind,LL)
#Assign group and format id
DF$Group <- rownames(DF)
DF <- DF[,c(6,1:5)]
rownames(DF)<-NULL
DF$Group <- gsub("\\..*","",DF$Group)
#Write to csv
write.csv(DF,file='DF.csv')
```

You will get this. I hope this helps.

```
    Group ID variable value.x value.y value
1  Group1  1       1h       3       7     7
2  Group1  1       2h       5       3     3
3  Group1  1       3h       6       0     0
4  Group1  2       1h       1       1     1
5  Group1  2       2h       8       8     8
6  Group1  2       3h       2       2     2
7  Group1  3       1h       7       7     7
8  Group1  3       2h       3       3     3
9  Group1  3       3h       9       9     9
10 Group2  1       1h       9       8     8
11 Group2  1       2h       0       0     0
12 Group2  1       3h       0       1     1
13 Group2  2       1h       0       9     9
14 Group2  2       2h       3       5     5
15 Group2  2       3h       1       3     3
16 Group2  3       1h       2       2     2
17 Group2  3       2h       4       4     4
18 Group2  3       3h       7       7     7
19 Group3  1       1h       3       0     0
20 Group3  1       2h       1       2     2
21 Group3  1       3h       0       9     9
22 Group3  2       1h       5       0     0
23 Group3  2       2h       5       5     5
24 Group3  2       3h       0       9     9
25 Group3  3       1h       7       3     3
26 Group3  3       2h       0       5     5
27 Group3  3       3h       0       4     4
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly this should do the trick. Not the most elegant solution though!

```
# function to extract the id's
extract_id <- function(x, y, z, id) {
  x <- x[x$ID == id, -1]
  y <- y[y$ID == id, -1]
  z <- z[z$ID == id, -1]
  
  id <- t(rbind(x, y, z))
  
  colnames(id) <- c("x", "y", "z")
  
  return(id)
}

# initialize new lists
ID1 <- list()
ID2 <- list()
ID3 <- list()

# loop over the data frames
for (a in 1:3) {
  ID1[[a]] <- extract_id(x = x[[a]],
                         y = y[[a]],
                         z = z[[a]],
                         id = 1)
  ID2[[a]] <- extract_id(x = x[[a]],
                         y = y[[a]],
                         z = z[[a]],
                         id = 2)
  ID3[[a]] <- extract_id(x = x[[a]],
                         y = y[[a]],
                         z = z[[a]],
                         id = 3)
}

# show everything
ID1
ID2
Id3
```